# execution context of database trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, transactions

I want to implement an audit log using triggers which gets fired on created, changed and deleted data to store some values. Those triggers should be able to use user ids which made the changes and which are managed by the web application. I have some ideas on providing this data, but I don't seem to fully understand what the execution context of a trigger is. I've read through the PostgreSQL docs [Overview of Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/triggers.html#TRIGGER-DEFINITION) and others but my question doesn't seem to be answered.

What I want to know is the interaction between a client session with one running transaction and the trigger execution and the lifetime of both and how they depend on each other. From my understanding triggers are executed within the database independently from the client session which created the event which lead to trigger execution. Is that correct? That would mean triggers and their processing wouldn't impact performance of the client request and the client can close the session at any time. If both are independent, how would a trigger get notified about a client rolling back a transaction, which would logically mean that no data got changed at all? Or are triggers onyl executed after committing a transaction because they run independently?

Or are triggers executed async within the client session which created the events which lead to trigger execution? This would mean that if the client closes it's session for any reason, the trigger would abort, too. Their changes are directly bound to the clients transaction and can be rolled back, too.

I need to understand the behavior to know what I would like to do in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18036082/2055163).

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Have you looked at existing audit trigger implementations?
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus  and 
https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger

Comment: No, triggers are not independet and asynchronous, the trigger is an inherent part of the transaction and it is executed in the user session. If rollback is issued after the operations ends (but before commit), all changes made by transaction and also by the trigerr will be rolled back.

Comment: @bma: No I didn't, thanks for the links. I can't use the newer one as I'm stuck to 8.4, but will have a look at the older implementation.

Comment: I wrote the original at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger, but Craig came and rewrote a much better version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding triggers are executed within the database
>   independently from the client session which created the event which
>   lead to trigger execution. Is that correct? That would mean triggers
>   and their processing wouldn't impact performance of the client request
>   and the client can close the session at any time

No they totally depend on the client session, as part of the transaction which itself is tied to the session.
See this excerpt from [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) (9.1):

> They can be fired either at the end of the statement causing the
>   triggering event, or at the end of the containing transaction; in the
>   latter case they are said to be *deferred*

From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18036082/2055163) it appears you're using 8.4, which doesn't have deferred triggers, so it's even simpler. Triggers run always at the end of the statement (the triggering event), which means before the acknowledgment of execution is sent by the server to the client.

A COMMIT immediately following would be a new instruction, and could not be executed before the trigger is finished.

Comment: Thanks, thats clear and simple. :-) This implies that a trigger has full access to everything I do within a transaction, especially created temp tables with non relevant data to the statement which caused the trigger to execute, right? What I mean is create a temp table, insert some data, execute the statement which leads to trigger execution and the trigger has access to the formerly inserted data.